# paramiko installation " Unable to import ImportError"

Tags: python, ubuntu, import, paramiko

I installed paramiko in my Ubuntu box "sudo apt-get install python-paramkio". 
But when import the paramiko module i am getting error.

ImportError:No Module named paramiko

When i list the python modules using help('modules'). i couldn't find paramiko listed.

Comment: What's in your site-packages and/or dist-packages folders? This snippet `python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"` will locate your site-packages if you don't know where it is, dist-packages is probably next to it.

Comment: maybe you used another python version?

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. i could see paramiko
paramiko-1.7.7.1.egg-info in dist-packages folder. but the import fails.

Answer (score 0):

To use python libraries, you must have development version of python like `python2.6-dev`, which can be installed using `sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev`.

Then you may install any additional development libraries that you want in your code to run.
Whatever you install using `sudo apt-get install python-paramkio` or `python setup.py install` will then be available to you.